# Is there any danger in populating a set using parallel threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

Can I populate a `std::set` object and edit a boolean vector using parallel threads in C++?

I am relatively new to parallel computing and am just learning to use OpenMP, and I have heard people say that it is fine to have shared data structures between threads, so long as they are read-only.

My question is, can I populate some data structures using a parallel method, so long as the order doesn't matter? Or is the reason you don't generally do something like that more than just that the order will not be preserved?

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
input: std::vector<Object> u_set // vector containing universal set

int NUM_ELEMENTS = 1000;
std::set<int> my_set(); // set to be populated
std::vector<bool> my_bools(u_set.size(), false); // vector containing set membership information (true/false)
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; ++i){
    int next_el = get_next_element(); // next element from u_set
    my_set.insert(next_el);
    my_bools[next_el] = true;
}
```

The code basically selects an element from the universal set and then adds its value to the subset and marks it in the boolean vector as a memeber of the subset. Is it okay to do this in parallel? or is it considered bad form? Would something like this be better?

```
input: std::vector<Object> u_set // vector containing universal set

int NUM_ELEMENTS = 1000;
std::set<int> my_set(); // set to be populated
std::vector<bool> my_bools(u_set.size(), false); // vector containing set membership information (true/false)

int max_threads = omp_get_max_threads();
std::vector<std::vector<int> > elements(max_threads); // vector to contain data from each thread, so not accessing the same data structure

#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; ++i){
    int next_el = get_next_element(); // next element from u_set
    int curr_thread = omp_get_thread_num();
    elements[curr_thread].push_back(next_el);
}

for (auto it = elements.begin(); it != elements.end(); ++it){
    for (auto jt = elements[*it].begin(); jt != elements[*it].end(); ++it){    
    my_set.insert(*jt);
    my_bools[*jt] = true;
    }
 }
```

This makes a separate vector for each thread and then combines them at the end. I know it is technically still accessing the same data structure, but in my mind, having the vectors separate within the over all data structure would give it an extra level of security from getting mixed up.

Is this a better way to do it? or is it fine to just access the same set and add to it as the algorithm goes?

Comment: The short answer is: no. `std::set` is not thread safe.

Comment: Only `const` member functions can be access concurently. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Thread_safety

Comment: Fair enough, is there anything that you can suggest in order to parallelise this code?  would the second way be safe? because it is not calling push_back on the same vectors?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call almost all non-`const` methods of a `std` container while any other thread calls any other method.  (`begin()` and `end()` and a few others are exceptions).

So no.

One technique used in other parallel libraries is that each thread accumulates changes in a sub-container, which is merged in a binary-tree like way by the worker threads automatically into the final result.  This seems less reasonable with the tool you are using.

Comment: So even the 2nd way will not work? keeping a separate vector for each thread?